# MC55 Barcode Application

Tags: barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

MC55 Barcode Application

Please excuse my ignorance on this as I only came across this requirement a day ago and my programming knowledge is C and Unix.

I want to write an application for the MC55 that scans a barcode, the user can then enter information associated with the barcode on two boxes on the screen. This information is then downloaded to a database on a Unix machine.

So what tools do I need?

Presumably Visual Studio 2008 and I can see various plugins, the Motorola EMDK for .NET v2.0, and the Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit.

Any help would be appreciated especially if it gives me some step by step instructions.

Again apologies for my ignorance.

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

You're exactly on the right path.  The first step is to choose your EMDK.  For example, choosing the .NET EMDK determines that you will need Visual Studio and will be writing your code against the .NET Compact Framework.

The EMDK package includes many useful sample applications that will help you to see how to leverage the capabilities of the MC55.